# Проверка размера файла загружаемого в input file

Tags: javascript, html, файлы, form, input

Ребят, всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста с валидацией. Всё работает кроме проверки размера файла. Нужно выполнить всё на js, про php знаю, но в данной ситуации нужно сделать на js. Прошу подскажите пожалуйста. Код выдаёт постоянно ошибку, он видит размер файла, я его консолил, но не сравнивает в функции if ("sizeFile.size < 2097152"). Проверка на расширение и количество файлов работает. Буду благодарен за помощь!

```js
function fileValidate() {
    var filesExt = ['jpg','png','rar','zip','docx','pdf','rtf','doc'];
    var $fileUpload = $("input[type='file']");
    $('input[type=file]').change(function(){
      var sizeFile = $(this).get(0).files;
      var parts = $(this).val().split('.');
      if(filesExt.join().search(parts[parts.length - 1]) != -1 && parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length) < 10 && sizeFile.size < 2097152){
        $('.success-info').addClass('success');
      } else {
        console.log(oFile);
      }
    });
  };
  fileValidate();
```

```css
.success-info {
  display: none;
}

.success-info.success {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="files" class="upload-file" name="files[]" required>
<p class="success-info">Файлы прошли проверку</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`files` - это же массив. Вы пытаетесь прочитать свойство `size` массива, а не отдельного его элемента. Можете использовать, например, перебор массива `every`:

```
if (filesExt.join().search(parts[parts.length - 1]) !== -1 && parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length) < 10 && sizeFile.every(function(file) {return file.size < 2097152})) $('.success-info').addClass('success');
else console.log(oFile);
```

Перебор вернет false, если хотя бы один колбек вернет false, то бишь, если хотя бы один файл не пройдет валидацию по размеру.

Comment: Подскажите, а как правильно вписать это в мою функцию ?

Comment: Я поправил ответ